# Date Parameters passed to stored procedure not working as expected

Tags: c#, sql-server

I faced an issue in my project where i passed the date as `09/03/2013 23:59:59` to stored procedure but saw in profiler .net converted it to `09/04/2013 00:00:00`.

To confirm I created a small test application(anybody can use it to replicate, I am using .Net 4.5 and Sql server 2012 express edition).

Below is test code:

```
DateTime startdate = DateTime.Parse("09/03/2013");
DateTime endDate = startdate.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection konekcija = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
            {

                konekcija.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = konekcija;

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandText = "[Interface].[uspTestDateParameter]";

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentDate", startdate);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchEndDate", endDate);
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        // Fill the DataSet using default values for DataTable names, etc
                        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(dataset);
                        DataTable dt = dataset.Tables[0];
                        //return dataset;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {

        }
```

Below is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Interface].[uspTestDateParameter]
(
@CurrentDate DateTime
,@BatchEndDate DateTime
) 
AS
BEGIN
Declare @table table (strt Datetime ,endT Datetime )

Insert into @table values (@CurrentDate,@BatchEndDate)

Select * from @table
END
```

The resultset returned is `9/3/2013 12:00:00 AM  9/4/2013 12:00:00 AM`

I could have attached screen shot of Dataset visualizer but cannot do so as it requires reputaion 10. but above are the values of two columns(strt,enDt) I get.

Can somebody please help? My procs failing in production due to this.

Comment: What are the datatypes for startDate and endDate in your .NET code?

Comment: DateTime only. They are also shown in code above.              DateTime startdate = DateTime.Parse("09/03/2013");
DateTime endDate = startdate.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DATETIME` is rounded as described here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

This article explicitly states that all values arounded to .000, .003 or .007 seconds. The user-specified DateTime `01/01/98 23:59:59.999` will always be stored as `1998-01-02 00:00:00.000`.

Instead of using ticks, why can't you do the following?

```
DateTime endDate = startdate.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
```

This would *actually* pass the date you've said you're passing (`09/03/2013 23:59:59`) instead of one tick short of the next second.

Alternatively, use `DATETIME2` as your SQL datatype, which, according to documentation, has an accuracy of 100ns (one tick):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx

Comment: Yes, I believe this is the case. SQL `DATETIME` is less precise than the .Net `DateTime`, thus a single tick (or even larger) could be lost. `DATETIME2` (added in 2008) is higher resolution.

Comment: Indeed DateTime2 is now recommended but I believe a single tick will still be rounded. You can specify fractional second precision for DateTime2 but I'm not sure you can go as granular as a single tick.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with rounding of the SQL Server `datetime` type, as AntP described.

There are two different solutions you could consider:

**Option #1**

Use a `datetime2` type in SQL Server, as Tim suggested.  It has a higher precision, so you wont be likely to round.  This is still tricky though as you have to be aware of how much precision you are sending and how much the type will support.  In other words, should it be `23:59:59.999` or should it be `23:59:59.999999` or will `23:59:59.0` suffice?  You will have to decide what makes sense for your application.

If your data always contains whole dates, you can change your input value to:

```
DateTime endDate = startdate.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
```

And that won't get rounded up, even with a `datetime` type.

**Option #2**

Use half-open interval ranges of `[start,end)`.  When the end date is exclusive, your queries are much simpler and you don't have to worry about precision.  When two intervals border each other, the end of one interval will be exactly the same as the start of the next.  There is never any ambiguity, because the end date is exclusive.

Instead of sending the range as `09/03/2013 00:00:00` to `09/03/2013 23:59:59`, you send it as `09/03/2013 00:00:00` to `09/04/2013 00:00:00` with the understanding that the exact end date is excluded.

In other words, a date is in a range if:

```
StartOfRange <= @TheDate < EndOfRange
```

Or put in other terms:

```
StartOfRange <= @TheDate AND EndOfRange > @TheDate
```

On the .NET side of things, you can still present your input terms as fully inclusive.  Just add a as appropriate to the end value before passing it into SQL.  For example, if you are asking for whole dates as input, then add one whole day to the end date.

Comment: If you go with option #1, you should accept AntP's answer since he proposed it first.

Comment: Thanks Matt...Option 2 is great but going with Option 1 since at this stage of my project it requires very less code change....But i wonder, why is implicit round off happening...shouldn't Sql server throw something like OutOfRange exception

Comment: @user2159471 Not really - it's just a finite precision storage format like anything else. If it threw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` every time the value you passed to it was so much as a 10,000th of a millisecond off its maximum precision it would be pretty much unusable. The value isn't out of range, it just isn't stored with that much accuracy.

Comment: @AntP - you beat me to it.  I was going to pretty much say the same thing. :D

Answer (score 0):

Tick is a very small unit of time ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx)). There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.

Try to subtract 1-2 seconds to see if it works.

Btw, SQL Server datetime can only store 333 milliseconds (e.g.: .000, .003., .006 etc)